# Kramdown Markdown written Ruby integrated in Node.js

Tags: ruby, node.js, post, markdown

`Middleware in my Node.js`

```
  functions.editorPreview = function (req, res) {
    var data = req.body.text;
    fs.writeFile(__dirname + '/message.txt', data, function (err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      child = exec('kramdown ' + __dirname + '/message.txt', function (error, stdout, stderr) {
        if (error) {
          return res.json(500, error.message);
        }
        return res.json(200, {
          text: stdout
        });
      });
    });
  };
```

`$.post method in index.html`

```
$(function() {
  $('#kramdown-input').keyup(function() {
    $.post('/editor/preview', { text: $(this).val() }, function(data) {
      $('#output').html(data.text);
      $('pre code').each(function(i, e) { hljs.highlightBlock(e) });
      MathJax.Hub.Queue(['Typeset', MathJax.Hub]);
    });
  });

  $('#kramdown-input').trigger('keyup');
});
```

So I'm writing my open-source CMS in Node.js called [Spectrum](https://github.com/alicoding/spectrum), and I was looking for a good Markdown editor and none of them that really impress me that written in JavaScript.

I have come across this one Kramdown and I really liked it.

I have zero knowledge about `Ruby`, but I got it to the point where it is now working with my CMS, but one problem that I'm concern here.

The code above I have make Kramdown to interact on the preview panel, but is this really efficient?

Because this is like we are sending a GET/POST request to the server every single time the user time a character.

I was trying to check if there is a better way to parse the data without having to write the file and then execute `Kramdown` to parse the file then sending data back.

Is there a better way to do this? I don't really feel good with my solution here :(

Comment: Why is this a Ruby question?

Comment: Because Kramdown is written in Ruby.

Comment: That's a very tenuous association when there's no Ruby code in your question.

Comment: Well @theTinMan the thing is I'm not familiar with Kramdown at all and I have zero knowledge of `Ruby` :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You may learn ruby from [rubylearning.com](http://rubylearning.com).
- Using the Javascript markdown parsers to render on browser directly:

  - [markdown-js](https://github.com/evilstreak/markdown-js)
  - [kramed](https://www.npmjs.com/package/kramed): kramdown compatible, used by gitbook.

Comment: Option two is not going to be my option I guess :(

Comment: why not? It's so many javascript libraries for markdown: [marked], pageDown, showDown... and markdown-js can be extented very easy.

Comment: I actually have tried them all, but most of them missing quite a features that I really need in my blog.

Comment: Why not to extend it? In fact I've extended the markdown-js to suite my requirement. Or you totally drop down the nodejs and use ruby rails instead.

Comment: Well I would love to, but extending most of the features that `Markdown-js` doesn't have but `Kramdown` does it is a bit of too much work + time to get in where they have it right now.

Comment: Myabe you should wanna the kramed.